# Elixir: Iterate over nested map and insert key value pair on each level

Tags: elixir

lets say I have a function that gives me a UUIDv4.

```
def get_uuid() do
  # do magic
end
```

And I have a nested map that can be n level deep:

```
map = %{
  name: "Alice",
  friends: [
    %{
      uid: "EXISTINGUID",
      name: "Betty"
    },
    %{
      name: "Bob",
      job: "Truck driver"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I traverse the complete map and on each level make sure that there is a key `uid` and if not, insert it with the value of a call of `get_uuid()`?

Expected result:

```
map = %{
  name: "Alice",
  uid: "NEWUUID",
  friends: [
    %{
      uid: "EXISTINGUUID",
      name: "Betty"
    },
    %{
      uid: "ANOTHERNEWUUID"
      name: "Bob",
      job: "Truck driver"
    }
  ]
}
```

It would already be very helpful without the condition to look for an existing `uid` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
defmodule Uuid do
  def generate(), do: :some_uuid
end

defmodule UuidConsistencyEnforcer do 
  @uuid_key :uid
  def run(some_list) when is_list(some_list), do: Enum.map(some_list, &run/1)

  def run(some_map) when is_map(some_map) do
    some_map
    |> Map.update(@uuid_key, Uuid.generate(), fn existing_uuid -> existing_uuid end)
    |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn 
      {key, a_map = %{}}, a -> Map.merge(a, %{key => run(a_map)})
      {key, not_a_map}, a -> Map.merge(a, %{key => run(not_a_map)})
    end)
  end

  def run(some_value), do: some_value
end
```

To test:

Given a deeply nested map such as:

```
map = %{
  name: "Alice",
  uid: "NEWUUID",
  friends: [
    %{
      uid: "EXISTINGUUID",
      name: "Betty"
    },
    %{
      name: "Bob",
      job: "Truck driver"
    },
    %{
      n1: %{
        n2: %{
          n3: %{
            n4: %{
              name: "Alice",
              uid: "NEWUUID",
              friends: [
                %{
                  uid: "EXISTINGUUID",
                  name: "Betty"
                },
                %{
                  name: "Bob",
                  job: "Truck driver"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Running the following:

`UuidConsistencyEnforcer.run(map)`

will render:

```
%{
  friends: [
    %{name: "Betty", uid: "EXISTINGUUID"},
    %{job: "Truck driver", name: "Bob", uid: :some_uuid},
    %{
      n1: %{
        n2: %{
          n3: %{
            n4: %{
              friends: [
                %{name: "Betty", uid: "EXISTINGUUID"},
                %{job: "Truck driver", name: "Bob", uid: :some_uuid}
              ],
              name: "Alice",
              uid: "NEWUUID"
            },
            uid: :some_uuid
          },
          uid: :some_uuid
        },
        uid: :some_uuid
      },
      uid: :some_uuid
    }
  ],
  name: "Alice",
  uid: "NEWUUID"
}
```

Comment: In order to account for `tuples`, etc. you will need to add `run/1` functions accordingly inside the `module` `UuidConsistencyEnforcer`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! Only thing: Using Uuid as module name yields an error from Elixir.

Comment: It shouldn't give you an error. I am able to copy paste as is inside `iex`. What is exactly the error that you are seeing, perhaps you already have a library with the name Uuid defined somewhere.

Comment: `[error] Loading of ~/app/_build/dev/lib/uuid/ebin/Elixir.Uuid.beam failed: :badfile

[error] beam/beam_load.c(1412): Error loading module 'Elixir.Uuid':
  module name in object code is Elixir.UUID`

Comment: Can you copy paste the code in here as is inside a new `iex`(e.g. do not do `iex -S mix` inside an existing project)?

Comment: Yes. That works. It is a small thing probably specific to my project. It is very easy to adapt the module name...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166854/discussion-between-kevin-johnson-and-ole-spaarmann).